# Does the Windows 10 edition of Minecraft Bedrock runs on ARM Devices?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-10

Windows 10 supports the [ARM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/) architecture that is different from the ones on Intel/AMD CPUs (x86/x64). An example of a Windows 10 device has an ARM Processor is the [Surface Pro X](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/surface-pro-x/8vdnrp2m6hhc).

Will Minecraft for Windows 10 run on devices using ARM Processors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime since the accepted answer (as of writing, the one by *3ventic*) was written, Minecraft Bedrock Edition has been updated to support ARM devices.

[image]